# Happybase filtering using rows function

Tags: python, hbase, happybase

I would like to perform a `rows` query with Happybase for some known row keys and add a value filter so that only rows matching the filter are returned.

In HBase shell you can supply a filter to a get command, like so:

```
get 'meta', 'someuser', {FILTER => "SingleColumnValueFilter ('cf','gender',=,'regexstring:^male$')"}
```

In Happybase you can add a filter to a `scan` command but I don't see the option on a `rows` query. Here is how it works for `scan`:

```
rows = tab.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('cf','gender',=,'regexstring:^male$')")
```

Is there a way to perform a filtered `rows` query (for potentially random ordered row keys) using Happybase (or any other Python HBase client library)?

I imagined it would look like this (but there is no filter argument):

```
rows = tab.rows(rows=['h_key', 'a_key', 'z_key'], filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('cf','gender',=,'regexstring:^male$')")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get with filter is equal to Scan with start/stop row.**

```
rows = tab.scan(filter="SingleColumnValueFilter('cf','gender',=,'regexstring:^male$')",
                     row_start="someuser", row_stop="someuser")
```

In Java, a `FilterList` combined `MultiRowRangeFilter` and `SingleColumnValueFilte`r will perfectly satisfy your demand, and there is an [example](https://github.com/sel-fish/hbase-experiments/blob/master/src/test/java/com/mogujie/mst/hbase/filters/RowFilterTest.java) about that.

However, as `happyhbase` use Hbase Thrift service, and it seems that [don't support](http://hbase.apache.org/0.94/book/thrift.html) FilterList, so I think the best you can get is to call the above procedure for each key in your example.

Comment: On reflection I left something out of my question, I will edit it. The query I want to perform is a `rows` query over a randomly ordered set of row keys. I  cannot use a row key range as the order is not known.

Comment: @dsimmie update the answer and i don't think there be a perfect solution with current ```happybase``` version.